# How to change the localization of the In-App priceLocale product in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator

How to change the localization of the In-App priceLocale product in iOS Simulator? 
I always get a prices in EUR, and I can't change it into USD.

Example:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{    
    NSArray *Books = response.products;
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] && [response.products count]>0) {

    }

    for (SKProduct *book in Books) {


        NSLocale *locat=[NSLocale currentLocale];
        NSString *strlocate=[locat objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];


        NSLog(@"\n\n\n Device country== %@ \n\n\n",strlocate);

        NSLocale* storeLocale = book.priceLocale;
        NSString *storeCountry = (NSString*)CFLocaleGetValue((CFLocaleRef)storeLocale, kCFLocaleCountryCode);
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n Store country== %@ \n\n\n",storeCountry);

    }
}
```

Device country== US

Store country== DE ( *always DE and I can't change it* )

iOS simulator makes it impossible to select the current AppStore. Is there any solution to the problem of select country of the AppStore in iOS Simulator?

Comment: I suggest you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com to request the functionality you desire.

Comment: @user3642225 have you solved it? is your mac region in DE? maybe simulator gets its region from the mac.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the store isn't supported in the simulator at all. Are you really sure you're running this in the iOS Simulator (the app that runs on your Mac)?

The price locale actually is dictated by the *store country* of the Apple ID you're using since that's the currency the user will be billed in. So you cannot enforce "always show this in USD" or anything like that (simply changing the currency symbol would be wrong, obviously).

But for development, you can change the currency for your sandbox account (or better yet: create a new account so you can test with different currencies). See [the *"Viewing, Editing, and Deleting iTunes Connect Users"* section in the *"iTunes Connect Developer Guide"*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html):

> To Set your Preferred Currency
>
> - Click on your name at the top right of the page.
> - Select Personal Details.
> - Choose your desired currency from the Preferred Currency dropdown.
> - Click Save.

Comment: Yes, I trying run this in the iOS Simulator.

I have multiple Apple ID accounts including the account in the USA AppStore. I can logout and login with different Apple ID's on the real device (iPhone) and get the prices of the country, for which Apple ID created. But I can't do it in the iOS Simulator. iOS Simulator always give the prices only in the EUR and I can't change currency.

Comment: Interesting, it seems that Apple has indeed lifted the limitation and you now _can_ do App Store testing in the simulator. Since I only test the App Store on the device I don't know if there are any limitations or issues with the simulator. If it does work on the device but not in the simulator, then it might be a bug and you need to file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I need this in order to automatically make localized screenshots from the iOS Simulator. Thank you. I'll try to go https://bugreport.apple.com.